# Unable to invoke Jquery bind function event

Tags: jquery

I am unable to invoke "addFav" event, please tell me if there any issues in below code:

```
var CCRemoteMain = {
addFav :function(event) {
e.preventDefault();
alert('called');
return false;
},

Init: function () {
alert('called');
$('a#fav').bind('click', addFav);
}

};

$(document).ready(function() {
// Call the default function to be loaded
var RemoteMainFunc = CCRemoteMain.Init();


});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try referencing the method like this:

```
$('a#fav').bind('click', CCRemoteMain.addFav);
```

I suspect the `addFav` method is not in scope in the `Init` method.

Comment: Thank You..So Much..!!! It is working now..with "CCRemoteMain.addFav".

Comment: Happy to help. Remember to come back and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your reference to the event is not correct, plus you have a few other issues with your code. See the corrected example below:

```
var CCRemoteMain = {
    addFav : function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('called');
        return false;
    },
    Init: function () {
        alert('called');
        $('#fav').bind('click', CCRemoteMain.addFav);
    }
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Call the default function to be loaded
    var RemoteMainFunc = CCRemoteMain.Init();
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9xkKG/